# I Have Two Models and i want those values which are not used by my another model by foreign key

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

```py
## Bilty Model
class tms_bilty(models.Model):
    bilty_no = models.CharField(max_length = 400,null=True, blank=True,default=increment_bilty_no)
    send_customer_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.bilty_no)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['bilty_no']
    
## Invoice Model
class tms_local_invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True, default=increment_Job_no)
    bilty_no = models.ForeignKey(tms_bilty,related_name="tms_bilty_invoice",null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have Two Models Bilty and Invoice.

Suppose I created three Bilty numbers and i created two invoice by passing two different Bilty numbers.
So i want to return third Bilty no which are not used in invoice model.

Any Query Regarding This So that i get those Bilty no which are not used by invoice model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those Bilty no which are not used by invoice model, you can iterate over **all the entries** in the Bilty **model** and using `related_name` you can check if current query object is in relationship with
invoice model.

Below code should work

```
ans=[]
for bilty in tms_bilty.objects.all():
    if not bilty.tms_bilty_invoice.all():
        ans.append(bilty.bilty_no)
```